# is there a way for a function to return a JSON from a url instead of printing it Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch-api

**I want a function that returns a json from a given url using the fetch api** (and also if you have a better API option, please tell me, because I'm still learning about promises and etc.)

---

**What I tried:**

```
// [1] with await, I couldn't return, just print on the console
// what needs to change to be able to return instead of printing???
function displayJson1(url) {
    async function getJsonPromise(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const promise = response.json();  // should i put an await here?? the result was the same
        return promise;
    }

    const promise = getJsonPromise(url);
    promise.then((data) => console.log(data));
}


// [2] with .then, I couldn't return, just print on the console
// what needs to change to be able to return instead of printing???
function displayJson2(url) {
    const fetchPromise = fetch(url);

    fetchPromise
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

in both cases I tried replacing

```
console.log(data)
```

by

```
let json;
json = data;

return json;
```

But for some reason it didn't work, if you could also explain to me why `json = data` didn't work I would be grateful.

**What i expected/wanted to happen:** return the JSON (with the fetch API, using then or await, and if you can show me how I can make the 2 functions return a JSON with both syntaxes it would be even better to learn!)

**what actually resulted:** both functions, `displayJson1` and `displayJson2` are printing the JSON (when in fact I just wanted to return the JSON)

---

in short, instead of `displayJson1` and `displayJson2` functions I want `getJson1` (using await) and `getJson2` (using .then) functions

Comment: What do you mean don't work?  is there any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Just write the one function, you dont need to write two functions.

```
async function getJsonPromise(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return response.json();
    }
```

and when you call function just call it like given below.

```
getJsonPromise().then((response)=>{
            console.log("Data: ",response.data)
        })
```

Comment: but I want it all inside the function, I don't want to use then or anything else outside, I want a getJson function that brings me the json directly (If that is possible..)

Comment: I also wanted functions with the 2 syntaxes more for learning, to get used to it